# Prolog store results of a function

Tags: prolog

I am learning the Prolog language. I am implementing a program to transfer money between two users. I have this exchange of money:

```
user(alice). 
user(bob).
money(alice,10).
money(bob,20).
exchange(UserSend, UserRec, Money) :-
   check(UserSend,Money),
   retract(wallet(UserSend, MoneySend)),
   TotalSend is MoneySend - Money,
   assertz(wallet(UserSend, TotalSend)),
   retract(wallet(UserRec, MoneyRec)),
   TotalRec is MoneyRec + Money,
   assertz(wallet(UserRec, TotalRec)).
```

In this case, if I call `(alice,bob,10)` the result is that Alice has 0 money instead Bob has 30. It is possible to store this "transaction" in a list or other data store? How can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, but this looks more like *linear temporal logic (LTL)*, or *constraint handling rules (CHR)*. Although it is possible alter the Prolog facts, this is usually *not* really a good idea.

Comment: Not clear exactly what you want to do. Are you wanting to maintain a persistent ledger indicating every transaction that has occurred?

Comment: @lurker exactly, in your opinion is possible to do this? Not persistent, only for the execution of the program